# PSR-0 Composer Autoloading causing class not found in plugin

Tags: plugin-development

I have composer setup at the root of the plugin folder with a few dependencies. I have custom classes in a folder at root we can call pluginX, I am autoloading its namespace with composer like such.

```
{
  "autoload":{
    "psr-0": {"PluginX": "PluginX/"}
  },
  "require": {
    "andrefelipe/orchestrate-php": "0.14.0"
  }
}
```

however when I try and use my class which resides at "PluginX/Models/Trips" like below I get a "Fatal Error: Class Not found..."

```
<?php
namespace Craft;

use \GoWander\Models\Trips;
use \andrefelipe\Orchestrate;
use \GuzzleHttp\Client as GuzzleClient;

class PluginX_TripController extends BaseController {

    protected $allowAnonymous = false;

    public function actionIndex() {

        // let's instantiate a Http client programatically
        $clientConfig = Orchestrate\default_http_config();
        $httpClient = new GuzzleClient($clientConfig);

        // instatiate the collection
        $trips = new Trips($httpClient);

        $trip = $trips->item('ING');
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was with how composer handles psr-0 and psr-4 autoloading, so by changing the `composer.json` like such, the classes were loaded.

```
{
  "autoload":{
    "psr-4": {"PluginX\\": "PluginX/"}
  },
  "require": {
    "andrefelipe/orchestrate-php": "0.14.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Had the same issue-- was trying to use psr-0, but when I switched to the psr-4 syntax it worked...